# Empty message <s:Body/> while calling WCF service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

So, I have this group of third party webservices I've been working with for some time without much trouble, but suddenly with one new service I've encountered this problem, where it kept giving me some strange responses.

After checking logs it appears that WCF message body is generated empty:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:mediate</Action>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink"></VsDebuggerCausalityData>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm calling service from code the same way as usual:

```
Dim nieobecnosc As SIMPLEWSProxy.nieobecnosc_TYPE = New SIMPLEWSProxy.nieobecnosc_TYPE()

nieobecnosc.wniosek_id = "8"
nieobecnosc.pracownik_nrewid = 100019
nieobecnosc.nieobecnosc_kod = "W"
nieobecnosc.data_od = "2014-10-21"
nieobecnosc.data_do = "2014-10-25"

Dim request As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest = New SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest(nieobecnosc)

Dim proxy As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortTypeClient = New SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortTypeClient("AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint")

proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUsername"
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword"

Dim proxyCallable As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType = proxy

Dim response As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message = proxyCallable.mediate(request)
```

Webservice's wsdl looks like that:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
   <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UTOverTransport">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
         <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
               <wsp:Policy>
                  <sp:TransportToken>
                     <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                     </wsp:Policy>
                  </sp:TransportToken>
                  <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                     <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic256/>
                     </wsp:Policy>
                  </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                  <sp:Layout>
                     <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Lax/>
                     </wsp:Policy>
                  </sp:Layout>
                  <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
               </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
               <wsp:Policy>
                  <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
               </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
         </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
   </wsp:Policy>
   <wsdl:types/>
   <wsdl:message name="in"/>
   <wsdl:message name="out"/>
   <wsdl:portType name="AbsenceCreateProxyPortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="mediate">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:in" wsaw:Action="urn:mediate"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:out" wsaw:Action="urn:mediateResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="AbsenceCreateProxySoap11Binding" type="tns:AbsenceCreateProxyPortType">
      <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#UTOverTransport"/>
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="mediate">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:mediate" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:binding name="AbsenceCreateProxySoap12Binding" type="tns:AbsenceCreateProxyPortType">
      <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#UTOverTransport"/>
      <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="mediate">
         <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:mediate" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:binding name="AbsenceCreateProxyHttpBinding" type="tns:AbsenceCreateProxyPortType">
      <http:binding verb="POST"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="mediate">
         <http:operation location="mediate"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="AbsenceCreateProxy">
      <wsdl:port name="AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:AbsenceCreateProxySoap11Binding">
         <soap:address location="https://192.168.1.3:8243/services/AbsenceCreateProxy.AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsSoap12Endpoint" binding="tns:AbsenceCreateProxySoap12Binding">
         <soap12:address location="https://192.168.1.3:8243/services/AbsenceCreateProxy.AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsSoap12Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsEndpoint" binding="tns:AbsenceCreateProxyHttpBinding">
         <http:address location="https://192.168.1.3:8243/services/AbsenceCreateProxy.AbsenceCreateProxyHttpsEndpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

I'm no expert when it comes to webservices and honestly I have no idea how to ever begin to looking for potential issue as I don't have access to service itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Bartek

**EDIT: Updated my question with some additional info, as it might be related.**

Usually, when I autogenerate code from wsdls provided for similar services, generated classes initially look like this (removed unrelated code for clarity):

```
Namespace SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect

    Public Interface AbsenceCreateProxyPortType
        Function mediate(ByVal request As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest) As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateResponse
    End Interface

    Partial Public Class mediateRequest

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Partial Public Class mediateResponse

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Interface AbsenceCreateProxyPortTypeChannel
        Inherits SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    End Interface

    Partial Public Class AbsenceCreateProxyPortTypeClient
        Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType)
        Implements SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

        <System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
        Function SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect_AbsenceCreateProxyPortType_mediate(ByVal request As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest) As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateResponse Implements SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType.mediate
            Return MyBase.Channel.mediate(request)
        End Function

        Public Sub mediate()
            Dim inValue As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest = New SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest()
            Dim retVal As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateResponse = CType(Me, SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType).mediate(inValue)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

But this code has issues: mediateRequest and mediateResponse classes are empty.

To fix this, I'm modifing mediateRequest class, so it could contain, well, actual, request data that needs to be sent:

```
Partial Public Class mediateRequest

    Public nieobecnosc As SIMPLEWSProxy.nieobecnosc_TYPE

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal A_nieobecnosc As SIMPLEWSProxy.nieobecnosc_TYPE)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.nieobecnosc = A_nieobecnosc
    End Sub

End Class
```

After this change the standard call:

```
Dim response As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateResponse = proxyCallable.mediate(request)
```

throws exception:

> End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element
>   'Response' from namespace ''

My usual workaround here, was to modify SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect_AbsenceCreateProxyPortType_mediate() function to return System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message type, instead of mediateResponse, may be bad approach, but it works for all other webservices in my application.

```
Function SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect_AbsenceCreateProxyPortType_mediate(ByVal request As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateRequest) As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message Implements SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.AbsenceCreateProxyPortType.mediate
    Return MyBase.Channel.mediate(request)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working!

**I feel so dumb.** My nieobecnosc property in mediateRequest should've been declared this way:

```
<System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace:="http://www.simple.com.pl/SimpleErp", Order:=0)> _
Public nieobecnosc As SIMPLEWSProxy.nieobecnosc_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim response As SIMPLEAbsenceCreateConnect.mediateResponse = proxyCallable.mediate(request)
```

and check the body

Comment: Unfortunatelly, tried it earlier with no luck, message body was empty. Updated my question with some additional informations, clarifing what I did so far.